# File specifications for HTML folder --> Kindle?

Tags: formatting, kindle

OK, so on the Kindle website there's all about how to go from .doc --> HTML --> kindle. But I write primarily in HTML, which is what Kindle uses in the first place, so it seems silly to convert to HTML --> .doc --> HTML again, then hope that nothing got screwed up in the conversion (and obviously I like the control of putting the file together myself).

Is there somewhere I can read exactly what the structure of a Kindle folder should be? (HTML file + illustrations folder)

I've looked, and all I find is .doc --> HTML --> Kindle.

What tags are allowed, what custom tags (if any) does Kindle need, etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Heya, I've migrated this to [Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/391865/file-specifications-for-html-folder-kindle), which is a better bet for file formats and conversion issues.  I'm still getting the hang of the mod tools, so the question is (incorrectly) listed here as being plain "closed" instead of migrated. Here's the new link: http://superuser.com/questions/391865/file-specifications-for-html-folder-kindle

Answer (score 1):

See [the definition of the mobipocket file format](http://www.mobipocket.com/dev/article.asp?BaseFolder=prcgen).